# mariaDB 10.2: sql mode has changed

Tags: mariadb, configuration, mariadb-10.2

The [Upgrading from MariaDB 10.1 to MariaDB 10.2](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/upgrading-from-mariadb-101-to-mariadb-102/#incompatible-changes-between-101-and-102) states:

> SQL_MODE has been changed; in particular, NOT NULL fields with no
> default will no longer fall back to a dummy value for inserts which do
> not specify a value for that field.

I am not sure about the meaning. On the [SQL mode](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/sql-mode/) it says that SQL mode is for changing some behaviour of handling SQL, for example to make it compatible with Oracle's SQL dialect.

So this change stated by the upgrade guide is referred to all the SQL mode or just a specific one? I can't find anything about this case on the [SQL mode](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/sql-mode/) page.

On MariaDB 10.1, with `mysql.cnf` setting `sql_mode = ''`, I've created a table

```sql
CREATE TABLE test (
  a INT NOT NULL, 
  b VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
) engine = InnoDB;
```

and then this queries fail:

```sql
INSERT INTO test set a = NULL, b = 'whatever';
--  Column 'a' cannot be null

INSERT INTO test set a = 42, b = NULL;
-- Column 'b' cannot be null
```

So it seems that already on MariaDB 10.1 you can't set `NULL` on a `NOT NULL` field.

Could you please provide examples showing how was the behaviour before and after the change?

Comment: What should be done when you insert `NULL` into a column declared to be `NOT NULL`?  The handling of this "incorrect code" has changed, so I cannot get too excited about the change.